# What does it mean to a integrate a function over a region?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a question like this:

> Integrate $xye^{x-y}$ over the triangle region given by $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,2)$.

I know how to integrate and all, but what does it mean to integrate the function over an area?

Comment: Have you learned (or started learning) double integrals?

Comment: actually, I just started.

Comment: That means that the given region in the $xy$-plane is the domain for the integrand function. And then there are two ways to interpret and thus to answer your question: what it means conceptually by definition, or how we handle such integrals. Conceptually: it's defined via Riemann sums that can be visualized as representing the volume under the surface that's the graph of this function over this region. Practically: often we reduce a double integral into a repeated integral, i.e. one integral inside another (roughly speaking).

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the explanation!